# Name the poker hand - 7 cards edition

Tags: code-golf, game

#### The Challenge:

In this question: [Name the poker hand](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6494/name-the-poker-hand) you had to take a five card poker hand and identify it. This question is similar, with two twists:

First, the output will be in all lower case. This allows for more golfing, as you don't have to worry about the capitalization of `flush` and `straight`

```
high card
one pair
two pair
three of a kind
straight
flush
full house
four of a kind
straight flush
royal flush
```

Secondly, with the popularity of Texas Hold'em and 7 card stud, we here at code golf should be able to score a **seven card** poker hand am I right? When scoring a seven card hand, use the five best cards for your hand and ignore the two you don't need.

#### Reference:

List of poker hands: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_poker_hands

### Input (lifted directly from the previous thread)

7 *cards* from either stdin or commandline arguments.
A card is a two letter string on the form `RS`, where R is rank and S is suit.
The **ranks** are `2` - `9` (number cards), `T` (ten), `J` (Jack), `Q` (Queen), `K` (King), `A` (Ace).
The **suits** are `S`, `D`, `H`, `C` for spades, diamonds, hearts and clubs respectively.

#### Example of cards

```
5H - five of hearts
TS - ten of spades
AD - ace of diamonds
```

#### Example of input => desired output

```
3H 5D JS 3C 7C AH QS => one pair
JH 4C 2C 9S 4H JD 2H => two pair
7H 3S 7S 7D AC QH 7C => four of a kind
8C 3H 8S 8H 3S 2C 5D => full house
AS KC KD KH QH TS JC => straight
```

Notice in the second example there are actually three pairs, but you can only use five cards, so it's `two pair`. In the fifth example, there are both a `three of a kind` and a `straight` possible, but a `straight` is better, so output `straight`.

#### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins!

#### Errata

1. You may not use external resources.
2. Ace is both high and low for straights.

Comment: Nice; I secretly hoped that someone would pick up the ball. Just wanted to note that I did not have any restrictions on the capitalization in the original question (clarified in a comment), So you could (and most/all did) output "Straight Flush". IMHO capitalized looks better.

Comment: You say input (lifted directly from the previous thread) *5 cards.* I think you meant to change that to 7.

Comment: @steveverrill You can edit posts yourself on stack exchange. Though I did it for you here

Comment: Are external resources allowed? There are lookup tables that will allow you to simply look up each card in the hand and get a hand strength.

Comment: Can ace be low as well as high for straights?

Comment: @NickT: Updated post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Ruby 353

This was based off of [Chron's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/6495/8265) from the original question.

This takes input as command line arguments. Basically we just iterate over all combinations of size 5 to get what type of hand it is. Each hand type was modified so that is starts with a number. ("royal flush" -> "0royal 4flush", "high card" -> "9high card"). This allows us to sort strings that were returned. The first string after sorting is the best possible hand. So we print that after removing all numbers from the string.

```
o,p=%w(4flush 1straight)
f=/1{5}|1{4}0+1$/
puts $*.combination(5).map{|z|s=[0]*13;Hash[*z.map{|c|s['23456789TJQKA'.index c[0]]+=1;c[1]}.uniq[1]?[f,'5'+p,?4,'2four'+a=' of a kind',/3.*2|2.*3/,'3full house',?3,'6three'+a,/2.*2/,'7two pair',?2,'8one pair',0,'9high card']:[/1{5}$/,'0royal '+o,f,p+' '+o,0,o]].find{|r,y|s.join[r]}[1]}.sort[0].gsub(/\d/,'')
```

Comment: Nice. The gsub at the end can just be a sub right?

Comment: @bazzargh no it needs to remove all numbers. The code concatenates 4flush with 1straight or 0royal to get "0royal 4 flush" or "1straight 4flush". If we only use sub the 4 wouldn't be removed.

Comment: Gives the wrong result for `AS QS JS TS 9S 5H 5D`. That's gonna cost you a character!

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley Hmm this seems to be a bug in the original code. I'll try and figure out what the problem is later.

Answer (score 5):

## Haskell <s>618 603 598 525 512 504 480</s> 464

Cards taken as a line of input. I think I've golfed this to death, but will easily be beaten by ruby etc using the same trick: if you generate all permutations, you get the forward sorts you want to look for straights, plus the reverse sorts you want for testing N of a kind.

```
import Data.List
m=map
z=take 5
q=m(\x->head[n|(f,n)<-zip"A23456789TJQK"[1..],f==x!!0])
l=m length
v=" of a kind"
w="flush"
y="straight"
c f s p r|f&&r="9royal "++w|f&&s='8':y++" "++w|f='5':w|s||r='4':y|True=case p of 4:_->"7four"++v;3:2:_->"6full house";3:_->"3three"++v;2:2:_->"2two pair";2:_->"1one pair";_->"0high card"
d x=c([5]==l(group$m(!!1)x))(q x==z[head(q x)..])(l$group$q x)$q x==1:[10..13]
k h=tail$maximum$m(d.z)$permutations$words h
main=interact k
```

Edited to inline "pair" and use number prefixes after seeing @FDinoff's entry, also composed map functions to shave one more char.

Comment: You can save yourself a couple characters (about 5 i think) if you get rid of u. `"one pair","two pair"` is shorter then `u=" pair" ... "one"++u,"two++u`

Comment: yup, I was just making that change after reading your code. Also the number prefix technique saves me another 5

Answer (score 2):

## C++, <s>622</s> 553 chars

four unnecessary newlines added below for clarity.

```
#include"stdafx.h"
#include"string"
std::string c=" flush",d=" of a kind",e="straight",z[10]={"high card","one pair","two pair","three"+d,e,c,"full house","four"+d,e+c,"royal"+c},
x="CDHSA23456789TJQK";char h[99];int main(){__int64 f,p,t,g,u,v,w,l=1,a=78517370881,b=a+19173960,i,j,q=0;gets_s(h,99);for(i=28;i-->7;){f=p=0;
for(j=7;j--;)if(j!=i%7&j!=(i+i/7)%7){f+=l<<x.find(h[j*3+1])*6;p+=l<<x.find(h[j*3])*3-12;}
v=p&b*2;u=v&v-1;w=p&p/2;g=p*64&p*8&p&p/8&p/64;f&=f*4;t=f&&p==a?9:f&&g?8:p&b*4?7:u&&w?6:f?5:g||p==a?4:w?3:u?2:v?1:0;
q=t>q?t:q;}puts(z[q].c_str());}
```

**Things changed in the golfed version:**

Rev 1: Changed all numeric variables to `__int64` for single declaration.

Rev 1: Golfed increment and condition of `for` loops

Rev 0: Changed octal constants to decimal.

Rev 0: Changed `if` statements to assignments with conditional operator. Rev 1: Rearranged further into a single expression for `t`. This required new variable `v` for one of the intermediate values

Rev 0: Deleted verbose output. Only outputs the best overall hand.

<s>Rev 0: Gave up on compressing the output text (difficult in C because you can't concatenate strings using the + operator.) Writing "flush" only once saved me 12 characters but cost me 15, making me 3 chars worse off overall. So I just wrote it 3 times instead.</s>  Rev 1: used `std::string` instead of `char[]` as suggested by FDinoff, making it possible to concatenate with `+`.

**Ungolfed version, 714 noncomment nonwhitespace characters.**

Loops through all 21 possible hands that can be made from 7 cards and rejects 2 cards each time. The suit and rank of the five chosen cards are totalised in variables f and p with a different octal digit for each suit/rank. Various bit operations are performed to determine the hand type, which is then stored in t (all 21 possibilities are output in the ungolfed version.) Finally the best possible hand is output.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "string.h"

char x[] = "CDHSA23456789TJQK", h[99], z[10][99] = 
{ "high card", "one pair", "two pair","three of a kind", "straight","flush","full house","four of a kind","straight","royal" };

int main(void)
{
        int i,j,q=0;                  //i,j:loop counters. q:best possible hand of 7 card   
        scanf_s("%s/n", &h, 99); getchar();
        for (i = 7; i < 28; i++){

          //f,p: count number of cards of each suit (2 octal digits) and rank (1 octal digit.)
          //t: best hand for current 5 cards. g:straight flag. u,w: flags for pairs and 3's.   
          //l: constant 1 (64bit leftshift doesn't work on a literal.) 
          //octal bitmasks: a=ace high straight, b=general purpose

            __int64 f=0,p=0,t=0,g,u,w,l=1,a=01111000000001,b=a+0111111110;

           for (j = 0; j < 7; j++){
               if (j != i %7 & j != (i+i/7) %7){
                                       
                   f += l << (strchr(x,h[j*3+1])-x)*6;
                   p += l << (strchr(x,h[j*3])-x-4)*3;

                   printf_s("%c%c ",h[j*3], h[j*3+1]);
               }
           }
                   
           w=p&b*2;                          //if 2nd bit set we have a pair
           if (w) t=1;
           u= w & w-1;                       //if there is only one pair w&w-1 evaluates to 0; +ve for 2 pair.
           if (u) t=2;
           w = p & p/2;                      // if 2nd and 1st bit set we have 3 of kind. 
           if (w) t=3;
           g = p*64 & p*8 & p & p/8 & p/64;  // detects all straights except ace high. pattern for ace high in a.
           if (g||p==a) t=4;
           f&=f*4;                           //for a flush we want 5 cards of the same suit, binary 101
           if (f) t=5;
           if (u&&w) t=6;                    //full house meets conditions of 2 pair and 3 of kind
           if (p & b*4) t=7;                 //four of a kind
           if (f && g) t=8;                  //straight flush
           if (f && p==a) t=9;               //royal flush
           printf_s("%s %s \n",z[t],t>7?z[5]:"");
           q=t>q?t:q;
        }   
        printf_s("%s %s",z[q],q>7?z[5]:"");
        getchar();
}
```

**Ungolfed output**

[image]

Comment: Since you say you are using c++ you could use `<string>` which does support + for string concatenation. Which then means you could probably use `<iostream>` and use `cout` However I don't actually know if any of those would lead to smaller character count.

Comment: @FDinoff what I could save: `" pair flush flush straight of a kind"`=35 chars. Once you add in `#include` savings are minimal, then you have to consider extra `",=+` and declarations of constants. Also I'm new to C++ and struggling with IDE and compiler settings (it forces me to use `scanf_s` and `printf_s` instead of the old "unsafe" versions and the help about fixing it goes round in circles.) `cout` might help a little, it's on my to do list, but probably for another program. The thing that kills `cout` for me is `using namespace std` I don't know if there's a way to avoid writing all that.

Comment: You should almost never need printf and scanf since you are using c++. There are other (safer) was to do the same thing. You could use `std::cout` to get around the `using namespace std`

Comment: @FDinoff thx for the tip. In my latest edit I saved 18 bytes w different string handling: `gets_s` & `puts`, plus `std::string` to concatenate, which means I must convert to `char*` to output. The golf I posted works with just `string` or just `iostream.` Bizarrely I must include both to use `<<>>` operators with `cin/cout` & `std::string`s. Overall, using both `#include`s works out 5 bytes worse, even though i can declare `h` as a `std::string` and avoid a separate `char` declaration. Predictably, I cant find a list of what's in `namespace std` in help (or an explanation about the operator.)

Comment: @FDinoff I agree, I wouldn't normally use `scanf` and `gets`, except for golfing, where programs are pretty unsafe anyway. I could shorten by 5 bytes `-s,99` if I could use `gets` instead of `gets_s`, but I can't get the compiler to let me. What surprises me is how unsafe C/C++ is in general! A few weeks ago it would have shocked me to find that `_int64 x=1<<y` gives the wrong answer for y greater than 31. But now I'm just mildly annoyed. Having seen things with array subscripts going out of bounds with no error message, I've got used to it. Is there any way of turning better checking on?

Comment: If you had used `1L << 32` (or `1LL`) the shift should have worked. 1 is of int type which on your machine was probably only 32 bits. Where long (or long long) would have been the 64 bits that you were expecting. Array's going out of bounds is a logic error and can't always be caught by the compiler (since it does no bounds checking). You might be able to get a decent amount of warning turned on if you used `-Wall -Wextra` as parameters to your compiler.

Answer (score 2):

### perl (>=5.14), <s>411</s> <s>403</s> <s>400</s> <s>397</s> 400

**Edit**: inlined a sub that was only called once, saving 8 chars.
**Edit 2**: removed a `.""` that was left over from an early attempt
**Edit 3**: instead of a temp variable that preserves the original `$_`, use one to make it unnecessary. Net gain 3 chars.
**Edit 4**: fixed failure to detect over-full full house (2x 3-of-a-kind). cost 3 chars.

Not quite a winner, but the straight detector is an interesting concept, I think.

```
sub
j{join"",sort@_}sub
o{j(map{{A=>10}->{$_},11+index(j(2..9).TJQKA,$_)}$h=~/(.(?=@_))/g)=~/.*(..)(??{j
map$1+$_.'.*',1..4})/?$1:()}$h=$_=<>;if(j(/(\S)\b/g)=~/(.)\1{4}/){$w=$_==19?royal:straight
for
o$f=$1}$_=j(/\b(\S)/g)=~s/(.)\1*/length$&/rge;$k=" of a kind";print$w?"$w flush":/4/?four.$k:/3.*2|[23].*3/?"full house":$f?flush:(o".")?straight:/3/?three.$k:/2.*2/?"two pair":/2/?"one pair":"high card"
```

Expanded version:

```
# We'll be doing a lot of sorting and joining
sub j {
  return join "", sort @_;
}

# r() expects $_ to contain a rank, and converts it to a numeric code. The
# code starts at 10 so the numbers will sort correctly as strings, and a list
# of 2 values is returned because A is both 10 and 23. All other ranks have
# undef as the first value and their proper 11..22 value as the second value.
sub r {
  return ({A=>10}->{$_}, 11+index(j(2..9).TJQKA,$_));
}

# Sequence-detector. Factored into a sub because it's run twice; once over
# the ranks in the flush suit to find a straight flush and once over all the
# ranks to find a straight. On successful match, returns the lowest rank of
# the straight (in the 10..23 representation).
# Required parameter: the suit to search, or "." for all suits.
sub o {
  j(map r,$h=~/(.(?=@_))/g)          # The list of ranks, in increasing order,
                                     # with ace included at both ends...
    =~                               # ...is matched against...
  /.*(..)(??{j map$1+$_.'.*',1..4})/ # ...a pattern requiring 5 consecutive
                                     # numbers.
  ?$1:()
  # A note about this regexp. The string we're matching is a bunch of numbers
  # in the range 10..23 crammed together like "121314151619" so you might
  # worry about a misaligned match starting on the second digit of one of the
  # original numbers. But since that would make every pair of digits in the
  # match end with a 1 or a 2, there's no way 5 of them will be consecutive.
  # There are no false matches.
  # Another note: if we have a royal flush and also have a 9 in the same
  # suit, we need to return the T rank, not the 9, which is why the regexp
  # starts with a .*
}

# Read a line into $_ for immediate matching with /.../ and also save it into
# $h because $_ will be clobbered later and we'll need the original string
# afterwards.
$h = $_ = <>;

if(j(/(\S)\b/g) =~ /(.)\1{4}/) { # flush detector: sorted list of all suits
                                 # contains 5 consecutive identical chars
  # $f=$1 comes first, so $f will be true later if there's a flush.
  # Then o() is called with the flush suit as arg to detect straight flush.
  # If there's no straight flush, o() returns the empty list and for loop
  # runs 0 times, so $w is not set. If there is a straight flush, the return
  # value of o() is compared to 19 to detect royal flush.
  $w = ($_==19 ? "royal" : "straight")
    for o($f=$1);
}

$_ =
  j(/\b(\S)/g)                 # Get the sorted+joined list of ranks...
    =~ s/(.)\1*/length $&/rge; # ... and turn it into a list of sizes of
                               # groups of the same rank. The /r flag
                               # requires perl 5.14 or newer.

print
  $w             ? "$w flush" :
  /4/            ? "four of a kind" :
  /3.*2|[23].*3/ ? "full house" :
  $f             ? "flush" :
  (o".")         ? "straight" :
  /3/            ? "three of a kind" :
  /2.*2/         ? "two pair" :
  /2/            ? "one pair" :
                   "high card"
```

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript 600

usage with nodeJS: `node code.js "7H 3S 7S 7D AC QH 7C"`

```
function a(o){s="";for(k in o)s+=o[k];return s}
b=process.argv[2]
c={S:0,H:0,D:0,C:0}
v={A:0,K:0,Q:0,J:0,T:0,"9":0,"8":0,"7":0,"6":0,"5":0,"4":0,"3":0,"2":0}
d=b.split(" ")
for(i=d.length;i--;){e=d[i];c[e[1]]++;v[e[0]]++}
c=a(c);v=a(v)
f=g=h=j=k=l=m=false
if((st=c.indexOf(5))!=-1)g=!g
if(v.match(/[1-9]{5}/))h=!h
if(st==0)f=!f
if(v.indexOf(4)!=-1)j=!j
if(v.indexOf(3)!=-1)k=!k
if(n=v.match(/2/g))if(n)if(n.length>=2)m=!m;else l=!l
p=" of a kind"
q="Flush"
r="Straight"
console.log(f&&g?"Royal "+q:h&&g?r+" "+q:j?"Four"+p:k&&(l||m)?"Full House":g?q:h?r:k?"Three"+p:m?"Two pairs":l?"Pair":"High card")
```