# Check my tunneling arrays

Tags: code-golf, array, decision-problem

Imagine you have an array of integers, whose non-negative values are pointers to other positions in the same array, only that those values represent tunnels, so if the value in position A is positive and points to position B, then the value in position B must be also positive and point to position A to represent both ends of the tunnel. So:

#### Challenge

- Given an array of integers, check if the array complies with the restriction to be a tunneling array and return two distinct, coherent values for truthy and falsey.
- The values in the array will be below zero for non-tunnel positions, and zero or above for tunnel positions. If your array is 1-indexed, then the zero value represents a non-tunnel position. Non-tunnel values do not need to be checked.
- If a positive value in a cell points to itself, that's a falsey. If A points to B, B to C and C to A, that's a falsey. If a positive value points beyond the limits of the array, that's a falsey.

#### Examples

The following examples are 0-indexed:

```
[-1, -1, -1, 6, -1, -1, 3, -1, -1]  Truthy (position 3 points to position 6 and vice versa)
[1, 0]                              Truthy (position 0 points to position 1 and vice versa)
[0, 1]                              Falsey (positions 0 and 1 point to themselves)
[4, 2, 1, -1, 0, -1]                Truthy
[2, 3, 0, 1]                        Truthy
[1, 2, 0]                           Falsey (no circular tunnels allowed)
[-1, 2, -1]                         Falsey (tunnel without end)
[]                                  Truthy (no tunnels, that's OK)
[-1, -2, -3]                        Truthy (no tunnels, that's OK)
[1, 0, 3]                           Falsey (tunnel goes beyond limits)
[1]                                 Falsey (tunnel goes beyond limits)
[1, 0, 3, 7]                        Falsey (tunnel goes beyond limits)
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so may the shortest code for each language win!

Comment: what should we return for `[0]`?

Comment: Expanding on ngn's question, are self tunnels allowed? What would the cases `[0,1]` and `[0,-1,2]` give?

Comment: @dylnan `[0,1]` is in the examples. "If a _positive_ value in a cell points to itself, that's a falsey"

Comment: suggested test: `[2,3,0,1]`

Comment: @ngn wouldn’t that make `[0]` falsey?

Comment: 1. "Imagine you have an array of integers, whose positive values..." - do you mean "non-negative values"? 2. "If your array is 1-indexed, then the zero value represents a non-tunnel position." - do you mean that if we are using 1 indexing we must handle 0 as if it were a negative value appearing in the 0-indexed version?

Comment: @dylnan not necessarily, 0 is not positive (unless you're French or Belgian)

Comment: @ngn if your array is 0-indexed then `[0]` is falsey, if it's 1-indexed then truthy.

Comment: @JonathanAllan the tunnel values are values indicating possible array positions. If your array is 0-indexed then every value below 0 is not a tunnel value. If it's 1-indexed then every value below 1 is not a tunnel value.

Comment: I just posted and then deleted an answer because I realized it raised an error on input of `[1, 2]`.  Maybe this could be a test case, because we don't seem to have one yet where something points to something that points beyond the index limits.

Comment: @mathmandan see test case `[1,0,3]` returning falsey.

Comment: @Charlie Right, but I meant something more like `[1, 0, 3, 7]`.  So in this example `2` points to `3`, which IN TURN points outside the array.  (My deleted code correctly returned `False` for the `[1, 0, 3]` test case, but would produce an error on `[1, 0, 3, 7]`.  So I thought I'd make the suggestion.)

Comment: @Charlie I undeleted my answer, so you can see what I'm talking about: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/171786/36885

Comment: @mathmandan interesting. I have added the test case.

Answer (score 8):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 47 bytes

```r
function(v,a=v[v>0],b=sort(a))all(v[a]==b&a!=b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZKxasMwFEX3fsUrhVaiNthxyaaOXTp06RYyyM5zLFCkIMkK@XpXjuymgTi4RCAQHs657z6brmZd3arKCa2ITzjzK/@erZOSWW0c4ZRyKYlf8TVj5TN/ZCXtalKRNE9gvMvzsxif9DWnAE/fpnXNEcheW9EroIC9FspZcBp@Py6Bqw14USF4NJbTh14ROFlgTJ8JRXZNkV9VZAnkMxQfXFr8o7DB0ePyaOpFrsGdRenRRvJbAosAj3Vkp0amw4/jLm5OfJlFaaiEqVrJDbhWKZQWwqr0ATcxQRqB6eSAl7zIgINwjW4doDphwnS4RUPo3C2EWEOaJHTC3YuFr89zoLRPVNA7SbHSYm5Vw2hbjRZKPOqwOSl2wg2ruv0H/IPW/QA)

---

**Unrolled code and explanation :**

```r
f=
function(v){          # v vector of tunnel indexes (1-based) or values <= 0

  a = v[v>0]          # get the tunnel positions

  b = sort(a)         # sort the tunnel positions ascending

  c1 = v[a]==b        # get the values of 'v' at positions 'a'
                      # and check if they're equal to the sorted positions 'b'
                      # (element-wise, returns a vector of TRUE/FALSE)

  c2 = a != b         # check if positions 'a' are different from sorted positions 'b' 
                      # (to exclude tunnels pointing to themselves, element-wise,
                      #  returns a vector of TRUE/FALSE)

  all(c1 & c2)        # if all logical conditions 'c1' and 'c2' are TRUE then
                      # returns TRUE otherwise FALSE
}
```

Comment: I would really appreciate an explanation for this answer. :-)

Comment: @Charlie : explanation added

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>66</s> <s>61</s> 60 bytes

```python
lambda l:all(len(l)>v!=i==l[v]for i,v in enumerate(l)if-1<v)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZDBCoMwDIbve4qMXRRasDp2GHPHPcFuroeOtViIVVwVfPrOKW47qNNAINB@/F9SNDbNTehUfHMosvtDAB4FoofSeOif622s4xiTmqu8BE1q0AakqTJZCivbH1pRdqp9V5TaWFBeQhmBoQ/fMRpG7sMO4FpWNm02H6p9CjjM1CgVEGD/qYvAp/yh9gTCFuyFgs5pQRbrqBnJ0SzaY3RSc5Sa3WnSsLvvOyziK6j@BtHKvRhfYthT7gU)

Answer (score 5):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>19</s> 24 bytes

```apl
×/<∘≢⍨×≠∘⍳∘≢⍨×0∘>∨⊢=⊢⍳⍳⍨
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qG@qp/@jtgkG/w9P17d51DHjUeeiR70rDk9/1LkAxOvdjCRmAGTbPepY8ahrkS0QgyRBaMX/NKAJj3r7IIZ1NR9ab/yobSKQFxzkDCRDPDyD/z/qXVX9qHerraGVekhRaar6o@4WdbfEnOJU9dpDK9IOrdDQMH7Uu@XQekNNHTMdDSMY21gHxtQwVDDQ1DBQALJMFIwUDBWAggoGClApI5AkSMQIIgJiHloP4hhrPupdA9KsYKypoQOU0gGqfNSzF@h0U00A)

Prefix anonymous lambda, returning 1 for truthy and 0 for falsy. The TIO link contains a "prettified" version of the output for the test cases.

Shoutouts to @ngn and @Adám for saving approximately a bazillion bytes.

An extra shoutout to @ngn for the help with fixing the answer for some test cases, and with making it a train.

The updated answer uses `⎕IO←0`, setting the **I**ndex **O**rigin to 0.

#### How:

```apl
×/<∘≢⍨×≠∘⍳∘≢⍨×0∘>∨⊢=⊢⍳⍳⍨ ⍝ Prefix lambda, argument ⍵ → 4 2 1 ¯1 0 ¯1.
                       ⍳⍨ ⍝ Index of (⍳) ⍵ in ⍵. ⍵⍳⍵ → 0 1 2 3 4 3
                     ⊢⍳   ⍝ Index of that in ⍵ (returns the vector length if not found). 
                          ⍝ ⍵⍳⍵⍳⍵ → 4 2 1 6 0 6
                  ⊢=      ⍝ Compare that with ⍵. ⍵=⍵⍳⍵⍳⍵ → 1 1 1 0 1 0
                          ⍝ This checks if positive indices tunnel back and forth correctly.
                 ∨        ⍝ Logical OR with
              0∘>         ⍝ 0>⍵ → 0 0 0 1 0 1∨1 1 1 0 1 0 → 1 1 1 1 1 1
                          ⍝ Removes the zeroes generated by negative indices
             ×            ⍝ Multiply that vector with
            ⍨             ⍝ (using ⍵ as both arguments)
         ⍳∘≢              ⍝ Generate the range [0..length(⍵)-1]
       ≠∘                 ⍝ And do ⍵≠range; this checks if any          
                          ⍝ element in ⍵ is tunneling to itself.
                          ⍝ ⍵≠⍳≢⍵ → 4 2 1 ¯1 0 ¯1≠0 1 2 3 4 5 → 1 1 1 1 1 1  
      ×                   ⍝ Multiply that vector with
     ⍨                    ⍝ (using ⍵ as both arguments)
  <∘≢                     ⍝ ⍵ < length(⍵) → 4 2 1 ¯1 0 ¯1 < 6 → 1 1 1 1 1 1
                          ⍝ This checks if any index is out of bounds
×/                        ⍝ Finally, multiply and reduce.
                          ⍝ ×/1 1 1 1 1 1 → 1 (truthy)
```

Comment: I think this doesn't work for (1), (3 2 1), (5 4 3 2 1).

Comment: `0<` → `×` I think

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 35 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @Shaggy*

```javascript
a=>a.every((v,i)=>v<0|v!=i&a[v]==i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZE9b4MwEIb3/orr0oIECYQqU8nYpUOXbhGDC5fgyvEhbBwh9b9TU5K2KR9hqCVLlof3ee@5d2aYSkteaF9Shs0ubli8YQs0WNaOYzzuxhvzGHyY25jfsa1J4pi7TUpSkcCFoL2zc7Z@6MH5rn@e0fmZuC4sl/BaVjqvwSlIcc1JQgQFcakVaILvzzUwmYHhKYItoZh784dmI4MEJs4ILRiihddogQfhDNoTEwp/0ZTFtclhB22ZOseDQmFQ9SAPHqwsp/MVfCkbH2nAx2pSyWVDSZDyMq0EK0FXUqJQwISgI2a9Xn6X7Y8auIzu4uDIdU6VBpT9xEmV/eXZsqeOnvXH9L2Cl@fBmn7bM0r@L7TbRDRX62n2PaGCN6zJ7l7wA9f9ZYfJLAXXg5tP)

#### Commented

```javascript
a =>                // a[] = input array
  a.every((v, i) => // for each value v at position i in a[]:
    v < 0 |         //   force the test to succeed if v is negative (non-tunnel position)
    v != i &        //   make sure that this cell is not pointing to itself
    a[v] == i       //   check the other end of the tunnel
  )                 // end of every()
```

Comment: Good thing I checked the solutions before posting a port of my Japt solution, which is nearly identical to this. You can save a byte with `a=>a.every((v,i)=>v<0|v!=i&a[v]==i)`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 65 bytes

```python
lambda l:all(l[v:]>[]and v!=i==l[v]or v<0for i,v in enumerate(l))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5BCsMgEEX3PcXvLgEDNildhNqLWBeWKBUmJoRU6OmtJpV2If/5/Mw4v9fn5NtoxT2SHh@DBvWaqCIZenWTSvsB4SicEMmoaUG4cpvCsQDnYfxrNIteTUV1HfMDZS2bE0M5lx92BRWDTMBzcobtfmZoE@4V/tdqv8Vm590X0WTTlXlpxYaqPwDz4vwKYrDpd/ED)

Comment: [62 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY7BCoMwEETv/YrpTSFCGksP0nyJzSHFSANrFImBfn2aaEN7WPbN7LC7y9u/ZifiKB@R9PQcNKjTRBX1oVPaDQhnaaVMUs0rwp2PqVkWYB2M2yazam8qquuYB5TtvrkwlLr9sC2oGPoEPHfOsOsrg0h4RPhfSnyDzcGHX4wmO23Zl07sqLoTsKzWeRDDmL6LHw "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Comment: [61 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY7BCsMgDIbve4rs1jIL1o4dZD6J8@CYMiG1pThhT@@0TrZD@L/8@UmyvsNz8SxZcUuo5/tDA3KN2MmojkI6JQTKyONpVMsG8UptFkciOA/Gv2az6WA67PtUBlhsOYwEWl1@ODVUBGQGWpQS2PszAZaxRuhfin2DQ@XqN2MoztT25RM7Kn4AWDfnAyABm79LHw "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 16 bytes

```
ị=JanJ$>L<$o<1$Ạ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///h7m5br8Q8LxU7HxuVfBtDlYe7Fvz//z/aSEfBUEfBJBYA)

1-indexed.

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-e`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 11 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
§JªU¦V«aWgU
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWU&code=p0qqVaZWq2FXZ1U&input=Wy0xLC0xLC0xLDYsLTEsLTEsMywtMSwtMV0)

---

### Original (w/o flag), <s>14</s> 13 bytes

```
eÈ§JªX¦Y«aUgX
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=ZcinSqpYplmrYVVnWA&input=Wy0xLC0xLC0xLDYsLTEsLTEsMywtMSwtMV0) or [run all test cases](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=ZcinSqpYplmrYVVnWA&input=WwpbLTEsIC0xLCAtMSwgNiwgLTEsIC0xLCAzLCAtMSwgLTFdClsxLCAwXQpbMCwgMV0KWzQsIDIsIDEsIC0xLCAwLCAtMV0KWzEsIDIsIDBdClstMSwgMiwgLTFdCltdClstMSwgLTIsIC0zXQpbMSwgMCwgM10KWzFdCl0tbVI)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>16</s> <s>15</s> 14 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
εèNQyNÊ*y0‹~}P
```

-1 byte thanks to *@Dorian*.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3NbDK/wCK/0Od2lVGjxq2FlXG/D/f7SuoQ4EmUFpYwgdCwA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W9o4OZ5eEKovZLCo7ZJCkr2/89tjSg@vMIvsNLvcJdWpcGjhp11tQH/df5H6xrqQJAZlDaG0LFc0YY6BkDSQAfENtEx0gFLG8DkjMCyuiAGWATC0QXyjCF6dcB07H9d3bx83ZzEqkoA).

**Explanation:**

```python
ε               # Map each value `y` of the (implicit) input-list to:
 è              #   If the current value indexed into the (implicit) input-list
  NQ            #   is equal to the index
       *        #   And
    yNÊ         #   If the current value is not equal to the current index
           ~    #  Or if:
        y0‹     #   The current value is negative
            }P  # After the map: check if everything is truthy
                # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: My try was the same except with filter. I don't see a way to improve on this.

Comment: [14 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3NbDK/wCK/0Od2lVGjxq2FlXG/D/f7SuoQ4EmUFpYwgdCwA "05AB1E – Try It Online"). You can push the current value of the `ε` with `y`. So no need for `©`, and each `®` replaced by `y`

Comment: @Dorian Ah, of course.. That wasn't possible in the legacy when I posted this answer, but should have thought about it when I made my golf earlier today. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 36 bytes

```perl6
{!.grep:{2-set $++,$^v,.[$v]xx$v+1}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZJPS8NAEMXv/RQjBm3opuSP9KB49eLBi7dSZZtO24XNbtidpA2lnz1uTGsVo8nCwjCwv3nvzeZo5KzOKrhZw2N9uJpuDOb3hziwSOBNJsx7K9l07pWL/d4rJ9HxWFtewXrsvfuw1mY0DyIG5zu7lMm5XDCAa3g1BW0rGOfaChJaQQK5FooskIav5gy4WkEpUoQSjeX@aO4YYYP473Tgwy589BsfMoj68U9cWvyGt47foKJ2SjOEtphZlCVaR71jEDtwG0F4TqFb9KfFuM/lRYPSkAqTFpIboEIplBa4lHqHK7/dRtw9sIPVvoedoK0uCFA1iL44fibu5JxUMJcBp1sLL88nIUGjJPmb109p40sGRnOys9FoYYmVdhuSIhPUrCQaYGsYKRjwJS8k3JPhQGjJHz3UHw)

The basic idea is to check whether the set `{ i, a[i], a[a[i]] }` contains exactly two distinct elements for each index `i` with `a[i] >= 0`. If an element points to itself, the set contains only a single distinct element. If the other end doesn't point back to `i`, the set contains three distinct elements. If `a[i] < 0`, the `xx` factor is zero or negative, so the set is `{ i, a[i] }`, also with two distinct elements.

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>19</s> 18 Bytes

-1 Byte thanks to [Luis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/36398/luis-mendo)

```
n:G=GGG0>f))7M-|hs
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P8/K3dbd3d3ALi3CQ1PTQ7cmo/j//2hdQx0FGDZHME1gzFgA), for the first one only, because I don't know how to do all of them!

Gives `0` if truthy, a non-zero integer if falsey, eg. for test case 6 gives `4`.

Please remember that like MATLAB, MATL is 1-indexed so 1 must be added to the test cases!

Never golfed in an Esolang before, so advice greatly received!

Explained:

```
n:G=GGG0>f))7M-|hs
                        Implicit - input array
n                       Number of values in array
 :                      Make array 1:n
  G                     Push input
   =                    Equality
n:G=                    Makes non-zero array if any of the tunnels lead to themselves
    GGG                 Push input 3x
       0                Push literal 0
        >               Greater than
      G0>               Makes array of ones where input > 0
         f              Find - returns indeces of non-zero values
                        Implicit - copy this matrix to clipboard
          )             Indeces - returns array of positive integers in order from input
           )            Ditto - Note, implicit non-zero any above maximum
            7M          Paste from clipboard
              -         Subtract
    GGG0>f))7M-         Makes array of zeros if only two-ended tunnels evident
               |        Absolute value (otherwise eg. [3,4,2,1] -> '0')
                h       Horizontal concat (ie. joins check for self tunnels and wrong tunnels)
                 s      Sum; = 0 if truthy, integer otherwise
```

Comment: Is my explanation too wordy? I want to make it obvious without going totally overboard.

Answer (score 2):

### Python, <strike>112</strike> <strike>97</strike> <strike>96</strike> 86 bytes

```
f=lambda l:sum(i==l[i]or len(l)<=l[i]or 0<=l[i]and i!=l[l[i]]for i in range(len(l)))<1
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##bY5BCsMgEEX3PcV0p6BgYumixJMEF5bEVjCTYNJFT28NYkuSLoT/n2@Gmd7Lc0QZo1XeDPfOgL/Nr4E4pXzr9BjA90g8bUoVORnswJ1TXIu26cOBQwgGHz3JI5Q2VZyCw4VY0vKKQXnXX5QlakpPXzkRsQGCwda4MKgTy9Pi34J6v4NnuDMPCl8deTgnnbplqcUP)

Returns `True` or `False`.

-10 bytes thanks to @Rod and @TFeld.

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 89 bytes

```java
a->{int l=a.length,i=l;for(;i-->0;)i=a[i]<1||a[i]<l&&a[i]!=i&a[a[i]]==i?i:-2;return-2<i;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVHBbsIwDL3zFR4SqJ2SqJRpB0qY9gGTJnFEPWSlZWYlRYmLhKDf3qUtdIB2sJ6f7dh@8VYdFN@uf2rc7QtDsHVclIS5yEqdEBZaPEeDffmVYwJJrqyFD4UaTgOAS9SSIgeHAtewczlvSQb1ZhWDMhvrt6UAnyZdY6IonaOmVbyATNaKL06OQS6VyFO9oW@GMo@ywngRcr4IIh@lWmE8n5zPLebjcYNPEh02XiwlvuGMh5FJqTSah3OMqjpqZ7aT3B6UWrIgL5sAnIBPWG@vf@706kLF@loXCG55wOAu/8IgZHDpEPzzOnxowLvYfd1DnjcF08c13IZ3oSupOr3Nx7WaW8WzTrffy14eLaU7UZQk9u5ClHnDkZ3ByI70kN1c/t0YdbSCiu6QXtPGZ5CJxumY3w2sBo1V9S8)

### Credits

- -3 bytes thanks to [AlexRacer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/60517/alexracer)
- -6 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)

Comment: Could have been [87 bytes](https://tio.run/##bVFNa8MwDL33V2iFjmQ4JlvHDm1T2HGHwqDHkIOWOqm7xCm2UihtfnvmxP1mB6P3nmRJD21wh8Fm9dvKcltpgo3lvCZZ8KxWKclK8ZfpYFv/FDKFtEBjYIFSwWEAcFINIdmwq@QKSpvzlqSlyuMEUOfG70sBvrVYyRRJzKSiOJlDFrUYzK/zDGmBJf9StHRIo8qFFzLkhVA5rX2ORbFASteeDOYYy2QWHo9dfIrks4wijDuS@O20n9jPsVuQMGQgOu0BcIDglV3exxWOzxAadqm1QnjLQwZ3@XcGbwxOHcJ/fr89NAicdl/3kA@6gvHjGnbDO@lMGuc3q7TXe@4dT5xv/2J7uTckSl7VxLf2PpR5w5GZwMiM1JDd3P1Ta9wbTpU7o9e18RlkvAOO@W5gM@he0/4B) if it weren't for that pesky IndexOutOfBoundsException. Maybe you see something to fix it easily?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I can see how to fix that for [102 bytes](https://tio.run/##bVLLasMwELznK7aBBLvIwk1KD0kc6LGHQCFH48PWryi15SCtAyHxt7uylTc9CO3MjndnkLe4R2@b/Lai3FWKYGswr0kUPKtlTKKS/HU@2NU/hYghLlBrWKGQcBwAnFlNSObaVyKB0vScNSkh8zACVLl2eynAt0oTESOlCyEpjJaQBS16y9s@TSrFkn9JWttKocxTx2fIi1TmtHE5FsUKKd44wltiKKKFfzp190sgxj2@SMdjEQQYdlzktvPeQL/WmKJUk4bgbAvgCN4bu56PWzm9lNCwq9YQ/j32GTz03xlMGJwn@P98PXka4FnuUffU9zrB9NmGcfhAXUBj82aVcvrMfeKZze1eY68PmtKSVzXxnXkuypzhSM9gpEdyyO5@g0@l8KA5VfZVnW6MyyDjXWGRaxc2g@407R8). Nothing shorter yet :(

Comment: [-3 bytes](https://tio.run/##bVHBbsIwDL3zFR4SqJ2aqCvTDpRU2gdMmsQR9ZCVlpmVFCUuEoJ@e5e0hQHaIcp79ovtF2/lQbLt@qfF3b7SBFvLeU1Y8qJWGWGl@HM82tdfJWaQldIY@JCo4DQCGKKGJNnrUOEadjbnLUmj2qxSkHpj/E4K8KnzNWaS8gUqWqUJFKKVLDlZBqWQvMzVhr4DFGVcVNqLkbEkjH0sPLnCNBHhdDqg8nx2QAh0wMH0SaDvo2BRrHOqtWLRAuOmjbvOXT87DeWGDIhhHoATsJfget7@4OwCoQmuWhsIb3kYwF3@NYAogKFC@M/r6KEA62P3uoc8c4LZ4xh2wrvQhTS9X/d9nefO8bz37V9tL4@G8h2vauJ7uycqvPHEzGFiJmoc3Oz/XWt5NJyqfp2eK@MHUHAHeub3DZuRO037Cw "Java (JDK 10) – Try It Online") - omit `r` and break out of the loop analogous to [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/169335/60517)

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://gitlab.com/n9n/k), 33 bytes

```
{*/(x<0)|(x<#x)&(~x=!#x)&x=x?x?x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYzdCsIwDIXvfYoMRVqx2B/xonH4IGMwbyoymTB2kTG3V6/tWkZCcki@c1rRvTrvnZ1OF0Z3yX9h7okf2UJlEQWV9Ag1@8FOh2pceuuAsPm2yBr3fH@QcMSe1/NuqISC1Le8Tdqo6vBVIJOQoFBGcQUNKyc3SAdP/GeHDp4VFVGL7CtyUAwPV7Plg0nAOYL@Dw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/), 52 bytes

```
{o=!(i=0);it.each{e->o&=e<0||(it[e]==i&&i-e);i++};o}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZFPS8NAEMXv@RRjKfm/ZU3FQ@q0J68qeJKQQ5pO60LphuxWlDSfPW4TakDdHhZm9u178xt2V0v58dVpUrosFCnM0tz56WbVUfsZu43hcu7Hcn4p81jXRwp@24zGLRKPwbi2xV791e5iSIw8hPMr@UmPMETZAJKe4f9BbNCZlcQS2y99Ns6vLG7YbLHWeSPpGrtG4o0vkAcLoWdUlO8NsaV0kR746eQLnVGOKFxXMDJPoqhdyHb8xt4BjYglsKUDUNXioPcHmEwFIMK0WfsiaOGlUIo2K9P75wtEufLeHl@91AvDp@cwBAb0WVGpaZOCBxHIoJ04rdN9Aw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 48 bytes

```hs
(all=<< \u(x,y)->y<0||x/=y&&elem(y,x)u).zip[0..]
```

[Verify all testcases!](https://tio.run/##bZDBCoJAEIbvPsWAIAq7tmrURQOJ8FLhpZNJeFBaWmVJBS17dts0MaWFhZl//m9mmGuU32LG2ieWYe8evZPr7WDr@yDjl5SAA@dWjRhzbBvOpVqhWsOb2iZNUy2cWlFiFqdqjSqt1PQH5QHR9bClGS@LXLCBBN8XYAPB8FdjaA1hiEavEMhvThBM6ksEppB6lMxps@s6Z4yOmbTFvTal5wb8cVjz7cSIifSnjmAddmIoSWlEM3GONOKHC6j8TrMCdEg06C/VvgE)

### Explanation

Let's first ungolf the code a bit. As `f =<< g` is the same as `\x -> f (g x) x`, the code is equivalent to

```hs
(\u->all(\(x,y)->y<0||x/=y&&elem(y,x)u)u).zip[0..]
```

which is a bit clearer.

```hs
(\u ->                                  -- given u, return
    all (\(x, y) ->                     -- whether for all elements (x, y) of u
            y < 0 ||                    -- either y < 0, or
            x /= y && elem (y, x) u     -- (x /= y) and ((y, x) is in u)
        )
    u
) . zip [0..]                           -- given the array a (implicitly via point-free style),
                                        -- return the array augmented with indices (it's the u above)
```

This solution is based on a simple observation: let `a` be the input array, and `u` the list of pairs `(i, a[i])` where `i` is an index. Then `a` is a valid array if and only if for every `(x, y)` in `u` with `y >= 0`, the pair `(y, x)` belongs to `u` as well.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 22 bytes

```
¬Φθ∨⁼ικ¬∨‹ι⁰∧‹ιＬθ⁼κ§θι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMMvv0TDLTOnJLVIo1BHwb9Iw7WwNDGnWCNTRyFbU0cBJA0U9EktBgsZAIUc81LgfJ/UvPSSDI1CTaA4VGM2UEWJZ15KagXIwExNGLD@/z86WtdQRwGGzRBMYxgzNva/blkOAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs `-` for truthy and nothing for falsy. Note: Inputting an empty array seems to crash Charcoal, but for now you can enter a space instead, which is near enough. Explanation:

```
  θ                     Input array
 Φ                      Filter elements
     ι                  Current value
    ⁼                   Equals
      κ                 Current index
   ∨                    Or
       ¬                Not
          ι             Current value
         ‹ ⁰            Is less than zero
        ∨               Or
              ι         Current value
             ‹          Is less than
               Ｌ        Length of
                θ       Input array
            ∧           And
                  κ     Current index
                 ⁼      Equals
                   §θι  Indexed value
¬                       Logical Not (i.e. is result empty)
                        Implicitly print
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a very Charcoalable challenge... :-)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pascal (FPC)](https://www.freepascal.org/), <s>165</s> <s>155</s> 153 bytes

```pascal
function f(a:array of int32):byte;var i:int32;begin f:=1;for i:=0to length(a)-1do if a[i]>-1then if(a[i]=i)or(a[i]>length(a))or(a[a[i]]<>i)then f:=0;end;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZDdasQgEIXv@xRzqTAWTbZbiE1eZMmFm9XdgaCLtS379KkxbEtZKwgz53xz/Lma98nMwl2nZXEffkoUPDhmOhOjuUFwQD61De@Ot2T1p4lAXVH00Z4po12vtAur3MsUYLb@nC7McKFOAciBOdA4CJUu1ueWrW1PPMRSDT/4pqza@DYQL3jOltr6k17KWU8AX5GSnT1z7CAUwn3vf8v2Xo6c678TWZaPqkSosDuEJhtbmPw3r6lGis2pzdRhsdJt/cb5SRWjIsmyHo0WG1Qo8RX3@IK7AuRPfV6@AQ)

Made function this time because the input is array. Returns `1` for truthy and `0` for falsey.

Answer (score 1):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), 60 bytes

```
import StdEnv
@l=and[v<0||l%(v,v)==[i]&&v<>i\\v<-l&i<-[0..]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZBLS8QwFIXX9ldcEEsLyVA74qqRWagguBDGXZpF6EMCaTK0SUCY327MNPOwziJw8nHPuZfTyI4rP@jWyg4GLpQXw06PBramfVEu2UjCVUtdVez38i5zyOWEUMHS1FVPoq5dhWUqKkyL1YoxvzV8NMktmG4yExCgGcX3CE7v8SLXJ8kQfI62y1Fyk9FAigUoEBwmXrmcjuQBQRlgtBdXCeUcfbQtgsuY/ScKR4r/bVgY5yMPQ@urQ8OmpfGSw0IHvVWNEVqFGjYJgVBjqOMMhdpZA4SAtiaoHOoashmiM6pwLJL5n6aX/Gvy@O3dP38rPogmfj4kN70eh18)

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), 142 bytes

Vastly over-complicated monster version:

```
import StdEnv,Data.List,Data.Maybe
$l=and[?i(mapMaybe((!?)l)j)j\\i<-l&j<-map((!?)l)l|i>=0]with?a(Just(Just c))(Just b)=a==c&&b<>c;?_ _ _=False
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZFvS8MwEMZf209x4hgJJFI38Y3N@mYKygRhvmuLZFmnGWk62qsy8LNbs2Z/rBISnvxy99xxUSaXti3KZWNyKKS2rS42ZYUwx@Wd/WBTifJypmv06kluF3kwMELaZRJrUshNhwg5j6mha7pOUx1xM1xH3L3tsfnSExFmnxrfY0kemxq7AxSlXiyokEKo4XARTdRt/ApuiXtp6rydo6wwuADMa6xBQEISfsXgsG9OcnyQGYOXqskpC85I4kjYAyGDXUTn7sk1g5GDPj385zDqrPdpPeOR9/5lxT3lfyr0Ersmd0Hjf426Sv3Ek0/mZrBqrEJdWjeGQSDA/YEbxxFqu2kQhICyQacopCmQDrIjirgfZNZ@q5WRb3XLH2btdGtloZW/PBuJq7IqfgA)

Explained:

```
$ l                           // function $ of `l` is
 = and [                      // true when all elements are true
  ?                           // apply ? to
   i                          // the element `i` of `l`
   (mapMaybe                  // and the result of attempting to
    ((!?)l)                   // try gettting an element from `l`
    j)                        // at the potentially invalid index `j`
   j                          // and `j` itself, which may not exist
  \\ i <- l                   // for every element `i` in `l`
  & j <- map                  // and every potential `j` in
    ((!?)l)                   // `l` trying to be indexed by
    l                         // every element in `l`
  | i >= 0                    // where `i` is greater than zero
 ]
with
 ? a (Just (Just c)) (Just b) // function ? when all the arguments exist
  = a==c && b<>c              // `a` equals `c` and not `b`
  ;
 ? _ _ _ = False              // for all other arguments, ? is false
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>17</s> 16 bytes

```
.A.e|>0b&nbkq@Qb
```

Try it online [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.A.e%7C%3E0b%26nbkq%40Qb&input=%5B4%2C%202%2C%201%2C%20-1%2C%200%2C%20-1%5D), or verify all the test cases at once [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%25%22%25s%20should%20be%20%25s%22%2CQ%21%21E%0A.A.e%7C%3E0b%26nbkq%40Qb&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B-1%2C-1%2C-1%2C6%2C-1%2C-1%2C3%2C-1%2C-1%5D%0A1%0A%5B1%2C0%5D%0A1%0A%5B0%2C1%5D%0A0%0A%5B4%2C2%2C1%2C-1%2C0%2C-1%5D%0A1%0A%5B2%2C3%2C0%2C1%5D%0A1%0A%5B1%2C2%2C0%5D%0A0%0A%5B-1%2C2%2C-1%5D%0A0%0A%5B%5D%0A1%0A%5B-1%2C-2%2C-3%5D%0A1%0A%5B1%2C0%2C3%5D%0A0%0A%5B1%5D%0A0&debug=0&input_size=2).

```
.A.e|>0b&nbkq@QbkQ   Implicit: Q=eval(input())
                     Trailing k, Q inferred
  .e             Q   Map the input with b=element, k=index, using:
     >0b               0>b
    |                  OR (
         nbk           b != k
        &              AND
            q@Qbk      Q[b] == k)
.A                   Check if all elements are truthy
```

*Edit: realised that the trailing k was also unnecessary*

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 44 bytes

```ruby
->a{a.all?{|x|x<0||(w=a[x])&&x!=w&&a[w]==x}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5BC8IwDIXv/op4KQrtqJt4svpDQg7xsNOEIUgz1v722q4WPYR8eTzy3uv9WNLokrnxyh1P030NEuRqQzh4xyh0VEr2zivF6Mk5iTEhmpOGNpcfDg1J7zCDLdtq2O6zhj5jtdg/V/81mspVb4IpytD@5YgNibonz6UqzICiYcxNKaYP)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 54 bytes

```perl
{$i=-1;!grep$_>=0*$i++&&($_==$i||$i!=($_[$_]//-1)),@_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZFRb9owEMff8ymukVsS6iwxbDyMpQVp6x4mtS@8hShywYDXYGexQ4eAz84cknSVQDDNkqW7s@93/7vLWJ5@2qviGWb7DeKhR/pX85xlKLkLgzbit7c3Nw5KwhDx7Rbxq9A4EUpi3/eI6@JBstvPZO4sabbxx5HzoX3vjuOxajuj7YPr9yPUAfYLWqMWVlnKtW@esLk@RiTe1SHh45@SC9vGX74OR8M7d2OBOcu1gxgeUBdCGKCkXwcBzU1g5piHKpTlXOgZ2NdeTxn32@@MTTSbwrVHSv@71I05zHO6hgEdCxsfUgEcQzMCEbu3n17KgP3ZfjQZ8sV2sSmP5n1rZyVJKSxJrMgjGJrb@2t2GzMGGOWFXqzByaTimksBXchMe1qBlvAW7AEVU1jxCYMVyxV1rcgAghjOniN2cIpNjtkBBnKB/UBTxd6xlYGXHFKVKCvoBVsqlq6YMsiPGDqGWnUe1M2fkmtFncOEzmpovpID9ewcGqFCwoTnkyKlOehCCJYqoGkqX9nUrTbVOanqCFQlwyvXC1loYKLMvzCt99swQur62IyI6paCpx@1BK/U0I3/F1GNtvsv46i7mEum4JmtpVldypdcl7sil7u5jNn/AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>95</s> 94 bytes

- Saved a byte thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat).

```c
i(_,o,O,Q,I)int*_;{for(I=O=0;O<o;O++)I|=_[O]>=0&&_[O]>=o|(Q=_[O[_]])<0|Q>=o|O[_]==O|Q!=O;Q=I;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZFva4MwEMZfr58iE1qSetJoS8eapkPYBsIgk/adExn9M5SuDrd3ms9uE6XrNqxdA8En5/1yz@WW1ttyWZYxjiAFAT54JN599SOWb9IMe1xwysQ0ZcI0iVfwKBDhjNNerxZpgX0dC6IwJFNa@DqkT5yLwr/mgvncY7JcYBe2sIYEsup6l@UZj3WQsI9MRTbY6H5OkAEZ5@s749H1nh7ujYnx7M7nShyzAqW1s0T5SqZbRr7xFSjcDRLTDI/pIbJmqLt62ambCZOd99d4h0neuVpgrDKCkOSWDeiwx0c5PEgJtzDo9wc2YT8x9Y@iliXBacIoIPs/GP2NjQA5iqw9Uf35i42bqjlVH6drShid6M1pa0/CsMmkVXOWfRmGziwJtMlkNR1dbtherWFu6lUu7c0@a9JuxOpqgG7aB6AxWe4B)

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 42 bytes

```
#=={}||(a=0@@#)[[#]]=!=a&&a[[#]][[#]]===a&
```

Pure function. Takes a 1-indexed list of numbers as input and returns `True` or `False` as output. Just follows the tunnels, ensuring that `0` maps to `0`, no 1-cycles exist, and all cycles are 2-cycles. (I'm not entirely sure if this fails on any edge cases, but it gives the correct results for the examples.)

Answer (score 0):

## This answer does not work. Here for illustration purposes only.

This answer passes all of the (currently) posted test cases.  However, it fails (raises an error) on other valid input, such as `[1, 2]` or `[1, 0, 3, 7]`.

How could it pass `[1, 0, 3]` and fail `[1, 0, 3, 7]`?  Well, it proceeds through the list, just like you'd expect.  When it reads an element `x` of the list `a`, it first checks whether `x` is less than `len(a)`, and immediately returns `False`, if so.  So it correctly returns `False` on `[1, 0, 3]`, because `3` is not less than `len(a)`.

But assuming that `x` passes that check, the code will then go on to do some other checks, and at a certain point it happens to evaluate `a[a[x]]`.  We've already guaranteed that evaluating `a[x]` will be OK...but not `a[a[x]]`, which resolves to `a[7]` when `x` is `3` in the `[1, 0, 3, 7]` example.  At this point Python raises an `IndexError`, rather than returning `False`.

For completeness, here's the answer.

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 59 bytes

```python
lambda a:all(x<len(a)>-1<a[x]!=x==a[a[x]]for x in a if-1<x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZDRCoIwFIbve4oT3Thw4DS6CNdlT9Cd7eJEDoU1xQzm0y91WF2o6WDww@Hj/84pmzordGglv1qFj9sdAY@olGdilWoPyYmyGBMjttxwjkkXhSwqMJBrQMhlOzfEllWua5BeQpkPwz98YzREQWAHcKleddZsPlQ7CgTMvFEq8IH9p86onukPtfchbEEnFPROC7pYT81IjnZRh9FJzVFqdqdJw/6@XVkkVlDuBtHKvZhYYugo@wY)

I wanted to do `x<len(a)and-1<a[x]...`, but of course `len(a)` is always `>-1`, so the above is equivalent.  This check is a total of 5 chained relations (`<`, `>`, `<`, `!=`, and `==`), plus a separate check `-1<x` in the `if` condition.

Python (conveniently) short-circuits chained relations like this, so for example if `x>=len(a)` then the check returns `False` before it gets to `a[x]` (which would otherwise raise an `IndexError`).